# Anaconda: Undo conda create

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I have anaconda3 using python 3.5. I wanted to experiment with something in python 2.7 so I opened the anaconda command prompt and ran:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

In retrospect that may have been overkill; I didn't need *everything* in anaconda. I now want to remove it. What I tried

- I looked for a uninstall executable for the py27, but couldn't find one
- the docs say to: conda - conda uninstall (but that returned: could not locate 'conda--'
- I also tried looking in control manager (windows) to see if it was available to uninstall, but it was not

**Question:** How do I undo conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda? That is to say, I want to go back to my original anaconda3 python 3.5 and no py27.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the create command, you are not replacing your current environment, just creating a new one.

You can see a list of your environments using the following command:

```
conda info --envs
```

Then, you can activate a specific environment using (replace py27 by the name of the environment):

On windows: `activate py27`
On linux: `source activate py27`

To delete the newly created environment use the following command:

```
conda remove --name py27 --all
```

The "all" parameter will also delete any configuration and packages installed with the environment.

**Edit**

New environments are installed inside the envs folder of your anaconda root so after removing it you can check the folder in case there is anything left, e.g.:

```
C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27
```

More info: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: will `--all` also delete the duplicates of jupyter notebook and other conda components too?

Comment: Yes, should do, but check the last edit so you can remove stuff manually if it hasn't been deleted.

Comment: The command `conda env remove <envname>` should remove everything, including the folder. Note the extra `env`. Also, the command to activate environments is now `conda activate <envname>` for conda >= 4.4.

Comment: I have conda 4.4.10 and I don't need to add "conda" to activate the environment. Just "activate" seems to work as specified in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to delete the environment you do not need any longer:

```
$ conda env remove -n <env_name>
```

In your case:

```
$ conda env remove -n py27
```

more info [here](https://conda.io/docs/commands/env/conda-env-remove.html)

Comment: Ok that could be it, but I also have duplicates of all the other anaconda things like: jupyther notebook, spyder and so forth. Will this remove all them too?

Comment: It should remove the entire virtual environment; that includes everything that was installed with conda in this environment, and that is not shared.

Comment: Shouldn't the command be `conda env remove <env-name>`, so `conda env remove py27`?

Comment: yes, you are correct, what was I thinking. Thank you.